# Why does this official React testing recipe using await/act/async actually work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I've been working with Javascript for a couple of years now, and with my current knowledge of the event loop I'm struggling to understand why [this testing recipe](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching) from the React docs work. Would someone be able to break down exactly what happens in each step there? To me, it seems magical that this works in the test:

```
await act(async () => {
  render(<User id="123" />, container);
});

// expect something
```

The component looks like this (copying in case that link gets deprecated):

```
function User(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  async function fetchUserData(id) {
    const response = await fetch("/" + id);
    setUser(await response.json());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData(props.id);
  }, [props.id]);

  if (!user) {
    return "loading...";
  }

  return (
    <details>
      <summary>{user.name}</summary>
      <strong>{user.age}</strong> years old
      <br />
      lives in {user.address}
    </details>
  );
}
```

There's no implicit or explicit return happening on the render, so how does act know to await the async stuff happening in the component (fetching etc)?

To me, this would make more sense:

```
await act(async () => render(<User id="123" />, container));
```

or (which is the same thing):

```
await act(async () => {
  return render(<User id="123" />, container);
});
```

or even:

```
await act(render(<User id="123" />, container));
```

But that doesn't seem to be how people use it, or how it was intended to be used, so I'm a bit lost. I've seen the same examples with enzymes `mount`.

I don't want to create a fragile test, so I really want to understand this.

Does it have something to do with the callback being async i.e. does that append something to the event loop last, making it so that the await waits for everything inside render to happen before resolving?

I'm drawing a blank here and am struggling in the react doc jungle, because **everyone** seems to use this pattern, but no one really explains why or how it works.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking closer at the source code of `react-dom` and `react-dom/test-utils` it seems like what's making this whole thing work is [this setImmediate call](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/shared/enqueueTask.js#L22) happening after the first effect flush in [recursivelyFlushAsyncActWork](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a724a3b578dce77d427bef313102a4d0e978d9b4/packages/react/src/ReactAct.js#L169).

It seems like `act` chooses to use this `recursivelyFlushAsyncActWork` simply because the callback has the signature of being "thenable", i.e. a Promise. You can see this [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a724a3b578dce77d427bef313102a4d0e978d9b4/packages/react/src/ReactAct.js#L63).

**This should mean that what happens is (simplified) this:**

1. The `useEffect` callback is flushed (putting `fetch` on the event loop).
2. The `setImmediate` callback "ensures" our mock promise / fetch is resolved.
3. A third flush happens by a recursion inside the `setImmediate` callback (called by `enqueueTask`) making the state changes appear in the DOM.
4. When there's nothing left to flush it calls the outer most `resolve` and our `act` resolves.

In the code that looks kinda like this (except this is taken from an older version of `react-dom` from the node_modules of my React project, nowadays `flushWorkAndMicroTasks` seems to be called `recursivelyFlushAsyncActWork`):

```js
function flushWorkAndMicroTasks(resolve) {
  try {
    flushWork(); // <- First effect flush (fetch will be invoked by the useEffect?)
    enqueueTask(function () { // <- setImmediate is called in here (finishes the fetch)
      if (flushWork()) { // <- Flush one more time and the next loop this will be false 
        flushWorkAndMicroTasks(resolve);
      } else {
        resolve(); // <- resolve is called when flushWork has nothing left to flush.
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    resolve(err);
  }
}
```

### Additional info (update)

Unless I'm mistaken this should mean that `await act(async () => { render(...); });` "only" awaits one event loop unless a new task is added by the latest flush. I.e. it's possible to add promises recursively if there's a flush in between, also micro tasks such as promise chains will probably resolve during the first loop (since they are technically "blocking" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#microtasks))).

That means that if you add a timer or something else in your mock or React code that might naturally need multiple loops to resolve, it's not gonna be awaited because the "after" event is not captured before resolving since the then listeners are not attached / returned to the outer promise (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Comment: I really appreciate the insights into internals of async act() 

This is so far the best explanation and really helps me to figure out why my tests occasionally fail